# how to run on an imported table and pass each row as a parameter to a query(SQL server)

Tags: sql-server

I have a CSV file that I load into my DB( Without using SSIS) with about 20 rows and 3 columns(as below):

---

```
**start_date_local**    **end_date_local**     **provider_unit**
  18/04/2017 16:00      19/04/2017 16:00         501638-52973
  19/04/2017 05:30      19/04/2017 23:00         501613-52345
  07/04/2017 14:30      08/04/2017 15:30         201447-20266
```

each row/record should act as a parameter in my query (SQL server) that consist the following 'Where' clause

```
((Transmission.Transmission_StartDateAccurate >= '**start_date_local**')
 AND (Transmission.Transmission_EndDateAccurate <= **'end_date_local'**))
AND Units.sn LIKE **'provider_unit'**
```

i would like to receive at my result set usage data (Which is in another table and that's fine) **of each unit at its specific times** - as follows:

```
start_date_local    end_date_local  provider_unit   GB USAGE
18/04/2017 16:00    19/04/2017 16:00    501638-52973    35.3
19/04/2017 05:30    19/04/2017 23:00    501613-52345    42.4
07/04/2017 14:30    08/04/2017 15:30    201447-20266    4.5
```

please advice:)

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: How are you processing the CSV?  Are you using SSIS?  Are you loading it into your database somewhere?  You are missing a lot of important details on how you are trying to accomplish this in your question.

Comment: Hi, I'm loading the CSV file into my DB , without using SSIS ,

Comment: Then just join onto the loaded table and produce your output in the standard SQL Set Based manner.

Comment: Queries work with entire data sets. Instead of passing rows one by one, load all rows into a staging table and use it in your query to update the final table

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading this data into a Staging table within your database, you can just `join` onto it to use the data in a set based manner, which will return your dataset for all instances.

Not having your full schema this is a bit of guess work, but you should be doing something like this:

```
select s.start_date_local
        ,s.end_date_local
        ,s.provider_unit
        ,t.GBUsage
from Transmission t
    join StagingTable s
        on(t.Transmission_StartDateAccurate >= s.start_date_local
            and t.Transmission_EndDateAccurate <= s.end_date_local
            )
    join Units u
        on(u.sn like s.provider_unit);
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot

Comment: Thanks @D.Guy If this answer was what worked for you please mark it as such for the benefit of other users.